# Perl - Pack Complex 16-bit Word

Tags: perl, binary, pack

I have to pack a complicated message into a 16-bit word that is defined like so:

- Part 1: Error State (Least Significant Byte)

  - Bit 0: Error type A (Least Significant Bit)
  - Bit 1: Error type B
  - Bit 2: Error type C
  - Bit 3: Error type D
  - Bit 4: Error type E
  - Bit 5: Error type F
  - Bit 6: Error type G
  - Bit 7: Error type H (Most significant Bit)
- Part 2: Mode/Status Additional Status is defined like so:

  - Mode: The mode is contained in the least significant 4 bits of the most significant byte. Mode numbers go 0 - 11.
  - Bit 12: Status Type A
  - Bit 13: Status Type B
  - Bit 14: Status Type C
- Additional Status:

  - Bit 15: Reset on/off

I can't seem to get the pack() command right. I want to pack:
Error type E, Mode 7, Status Type B, Additional Status ON

```
my $msg = pack("n",
    pack("C", 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), #error state
    pack("C", 7, 0, 1, 0, 1)
);
```

Perl doc, http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html, does not say about little/big endian when it comes to packing chars.

Comment: The *endianness* of a computer architecture is about what order the bytes appear within numbers consisting of two or more bytes. An architecture is *little-endian* if the first byte - the one with the lowest address in memory - is the *least-significant* eight bits of the larger number. Eight-bit numbers consist of only a single byte, so the question of which one comes first is inapplicable

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `vec` instead of pack.
Eg:

```
vec($i, 0,1) = 1;               # set bit zero
print unpack('b*', $i), "\n";   # 10000000
vec($i, 1,1) = 1;               # set bit 1 
print unpack('b*', $i), "\n";   # 11000000
vec($i, 4,1) = 1;               # set bit 4
print unpack('b*', $i), "\n";   # 11001000
vec($i, 15,1) = 1;              # set bit 15
print unpack('b*', $i), "\n";   # 1100100000000001
```

Answer (score 1):

`pack` produces 1 or more byte for each input, so it can't accept bits. Build your word first, then pass it to pack.

```
my $word = 0;

$word |= 1 << 0 if $error_type_A;
$word |= 1 << 1 if $error_type_B;
$word |= 1 << 2 if $error_type_C;
$word |= 1 << 3 if $error_type_D;
$word |= 1 << 4 if $error_type_E;
$word |= 1 << 5 if $error_type_F;
$word |= 1 << 6 if $error_type_G;
$word |= 1 << 7 if $error_type_H;

$word |= $mode << 8;

$word |= 1 << 12 if $status_type_A;
$word |= 1 << 13 if $status_type_B;
$word |= 1 << 14 if $status_type_C;

$word |= 1 << 15 if $reset;

pack 'n', $word
```

Comment: Could have written `$word |= $error_type_F << 5;` instead of `$word |= 1 << 5 if $error_type_F;`, but the latter allows the variable to be any boolean rather than just `0` or `1`.